# Subdividing a polygon into boxes of varying size

Tags: algorithm, polygon, voronoi, procedural-generation, tesselation

I would like to be pointed to information / resources for creating algorithms like the one  illustrated on this blog, which is a subdivision of a polygon (in my case a voronoi cell) into several boxes of varying size:

http://procworld.blogspot.nl/2011/07/city-lots.html

In the comments a paper by among others the author of the blog can be found, however the only formula listed is about candidate location suitability:

http://www.groenewegen.de/delft/thesis-final/ProceduralCityLayoutGeneration-Preprint.pdf

Any language will do, but if examples can be given Javascript is preferred (as it is the language i am currently working with)

A similar question is this one: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27055/what-is-an-efficient-packing-algorithm-for-packing-rectangles-into-a-polygon

[edit]: I have found something to start with, but it is not what i was looking for entirely:
http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squintri/

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem in a completely different, easier way.

As i was looking for my problem, it turned out to be a fairly complex one, both measured in difficulty to implement as algorithm (my opinion) and algorithm complexity class(es).

If anyone is having a similar problem, these problems are classified as 'packing problems' in general, with specific problems like the 'pallet loading problem'.

The problem i was interested in, is illustrated at the bottom of this page:

https://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/packing/

and a paper about this problem, with algorithm descriptions of how to solve the packing problem for convex polygons and curved shapes:

http://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/publications/bmnr.pdf

Some more information on these kinds of problems:

http://lagrange.ime.usp.br/~lobato/utdc/
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePacking.html

Comment: no i can not! i did not solve my original problem through either a packing problem solution nor polygon subdivision :/ entirely different and specific to my game so, sorry!